# How to display multiple users' image using Firebase storage on RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

Good day everyone, I am having a bit of a struggle trying to grasp the idea on how to retrieve data from my Firebase storage to display it to my `RecyclerView`. The way my application is being set up, each user is able to set their own user profile picture. So the way I store the picture to cater for every user is by naming the files according to their `UID`. See below:

[image]

**Here is my Firestore**
[image]

Now I am stumped as to how I am going to display it on my `RecyclerView`. Currently, my `RecyclerView` can display the user's `FullName`, `Email` and `Score` like shown below:

[image]

Here's are the code that I am currently working with right now:

**UserModel**

```
public class UserModel {

private String FullName;
private String Email;
private long Score;


public UserModel() {
}

public UserModel(String fullName, String email, long score) {
    this.FullName = fullName;
    this.Email = email;
    this.Score = score;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return FullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    FullName = fullName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}

public long getScore() {
    return Score;
}

public void setScore(long score) {
    Score = score;
}
```

**UserAdapter**

```
public class UserAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<UserModel, 
UserAdapter.UserViewHolder> {

public UserAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserModel> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserModel model) {
    holder.username.setText(model.getFullName());
    holder.email.setText(model.getEmail());
    holder.score.setText(model.getScore()+"");


}

@NonNull
@Override
public UserAdapter.UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_leaderboard_single, parent, false);
    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CircleImageView userImage;
    TextView username;
    TextView email;
    TextView score;

    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_username);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_email);
        score = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_score);
    }
}
```

**The Main Activity**

```
public class Leaderboard extends Fragment{

private RecyclerView leaderboard_recycler;
private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private StorageReference storageReference;
FirebaseFirestore fStore;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_leaderboard, container, false);

    leaderboard_recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.leaderboard_list);
    setUpRecyclerView();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(adapter != null)
    adapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(adapter != null)
    adapter.startListening();
}


private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //Query
    Query query = fStore.collection("users")
            .orderBy("Score", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    //RecyclerOptions
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserModel>()
            .setQuery(query, UserModel.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new UserAdapter(options);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    leaderboard_recycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    leaderboard_recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    leaderboard_recycler.invalidate();
}
}
```

I would be eternally grateful if someone can point me to the right direction on how to handle this situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your user model class should contain a property called "profilePictureUrl", which is a `String` type variable for storing the image url.
2. You should make a screen (`Activity` or `Fragment`) for user to upload their pictures to the **Firebase Storage**, and **Firebase Storage** will return that file url, just save/update it to your user object.
3. For displaying the images, use the modern image loading library **Glide**.

---

- Firebase Storage tutorial: https://youtu.be/r4HgdJKM5ko
- Glide tutorial: https://youtu.be/eiP-vnSM0OM
- My Chat app demo: https://youtu.be/iTXCn3NVqDM

Comment: Hey Sam, I have already made a `Fragment` dedicated for user to be able to upload their own profile picture. It then will be stored in the  **Firebase Storage** under their own `UID`. But I have no clue on how to make **Firebase Storage** return the file url and be stored inside the "profilePictureUrl" object.

Comment: Your question has been answered in the first tutorial video I gave above, expecially at this time: https://youtu.be/r4HgdJKM5ko?t=571. Once you get the url just update it or set it to your firebase user object. I also have a demo for this experiment: https://youtu.be/XfXAcdoeEZ0

Comment: My bad, Sam. The thousand of tabs opened is slowly getting to me, mentally. Thank you for the lead! I appreciate it!

Comment: @Scrin No problem.

Comment: Hey I got it to work! Thank you so much, friend. 

https://imgur.com/iFDbgWk

Comment: @Scrin Great! And don't forget to upvote or mark it as answer, that helps :)